# How Kafka replication works when open the log compact

Tags: apache-kafka

when I set cleanup.policy = compact to my topic A, and the topic A has 6 partitions and 3 replica;
My questions are :

- How Kafka replication works when open the log compact ?
- How Kafka keep data consistent between leader and follower ?

Answer (score 0):

Each broker is responsible for running its own LogCleaner thread.

Only closed log segments are compacted and are otherwise immutable.

Only leader partitions are written to by producers, and data lands within open segments. Therefore, only non-compacted records are initially replicated.

If there is a leader change, and you have not set `acks=all`, then you will only lose events that have not been replicated within that current "head", non-compacted segment.

Comment: Think about this scenario：broker config log.cleaner.enable = false，that means kafka will never clean the log；and the producer write 1000W message in topic A; now , i set the cleanup.policy = compact to my topic A;  how the replicas work between leader and follower

Comment: Then the compaction wouldn't happen, probably. Replication still happens only on new events, or missing segments, though.

Comment: As stated in the documentation - _If disabled those topics **will not be compacted** and continually grow in size_

Comment: You can try it，it would happen，and the log will be compacted;  My topic compact from 8000W message to 1000W

Comment: Not sure what W means here, but like I said, according to the documentation, then seems like you have `log.cleaner.enable = true`

Comment: 8000W means 80 millions

Comment: Okay, well, regardless, replication still only happens within the head segment